# Prove that this set is a manifold and also a smooth manifold

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

> Let M={$(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$: $\frac{x^2} {a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} =1$},where a,b,c>0.Prove that M is a smooth manifold.

I have proved M to be Hausdorff and 2nd countable  but unable to prove  that for each $p\in M$ there exists an open nbd. which is homeomorphic to open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To proving M is smooth, I have to take charts $(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}$) and $(U_{\beta} , \phi_{\beta}$) such that $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\neq \phi$ and I must show that $\phi_{\beta}  \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} $ is $C^{\infty}$ function, which I have done.

So, Can you please tell how should I prove it locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function $F:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2$, where $x,y,z$ are global coordinates of the real space (observe that you can define $M$ as the preimage $F^{-1}(1)$).
The function $F$ is smooth and it induces the differential map $dF_p:T_p\mathbb R^3\cong \mathbb R^3\to T_{F(p)}\mathbb R$, which is linear.
The representation of the differential is given, in this case, by the gradient of the function
$$\nabla F\vert_p=(2x/a^2,2y/b^2,2z/c^2)^t$$
whose rank is less than $1$ iff $x,y,z=0$, but $\textbf 0\notin M\implies F$ is a submersion and $M=F^{-1}(1)$ is an embedded manifold of $\mathbb R^3$ of dimension $3-1=2.$

Comment: how did you wrote rank of M = 2?

Comment: @XaXa regular value theorem

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question if you have some spare time:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305036/prove-the-existence-of-such-an-immersion ?